# C rename function syntax issue

Tags: c

When using rename, would using the full directory names work? I cant seem to get this example to work, though all indications are that it should. Anyone know why? Example;

```
original file location is: /home1/s/j/jb986132/402project4/402project4TEST/checkDirectory.c
final destination of file is:  /home1/s/j/jb986132/402project4/402project4TEST/c/checkDirectory.c
filename is:  checkDirectory.c
destinationName is:  /c/checkDirectory.c
active is:  /home1/s/j/jb986132/402project4/402project4TEST
```

Can I just write it as:

```
rename(original file location, final destination)
```

Comment: Have you *tried* it?

Comment: Yes, it doesnt work. I was looking to see if anyone knew why, since im providing the full directory name.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the standard itself has very little to say on what the *allowable* parameters are to the function, it simply states:

> The `rename` function causes the file whose name is the string pointed to by `old` to be henceforth known by the name given by the string pointed to by `new`. The file named `old` is no longer accessible by that name. If a file named by the string pointed to by `new` exists prior to the call to the `rename` function, the behaviour is implementation-defined.
>
> The `rename` function returns zero if the operation succeeds, nonzero if it fails, in which case if the file existed previously it is still known by its original name.
>
> ***Among the reasons*** the implementation may cause the rename function to fail are that the file is open or that it is necessary to copy its contents to effectuate its renaming.

I've highlighted the snippet in that last paragraph since it means any number of *other* reasons may cause failure, such as attempting to change the directory, or trying to call it after 6pm on the night of a blue moon :-)

You would think that, as a minimum, UNIX-like operating systems wouldn't have a problem provided the subdirectory is on the same physical file system since it would therefore most likely be a simple inode move.

However, the C standard seems to presuppose nothing about the underlying file system.